# Crop text in variable in Visual Workflow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am trying to manipulate a text variable in a visual workflow to reduce the text down to 30 characters to use as a default for an input field. Typically this would be something like ‘Left(variable, 30)’. I don’t seem to be able to do this through a formula variable as this must output a numeric. How else could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Formulas can, indeed, only do numeric, so they can't help here. :(
In the past for things like this, I have used a record update to post the full text, use a formula field ON the object to automatically do the LEFT(), then have another record lookup get the value from the record.

Comment: Interesting idea. I hadnt thought of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a VF page on the back end, and then having the page set a variable on the Visual Flow that meets that criteria.  It's a bit of a roundabout way, but it will get the job done.  You might need to dig into setting Flow variables from a VF page, but I believe I have done this about half a year or a year ago.